# I can't view my raspberry remotely

Tags: vnc

when I want to manipulate my raspberry by means of VNC viewer it shows me an error or that the desktop cannot be displayed. only connecting the raspberry to a monitor allows me to access. What I can do?

Comment: what have you done to enable VNC? does remotely mean on the same LAN or through the internet? what is the exact error? perhaps you're doing something else wrong, you've provided no description at all of your setup

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a resolution in raspi-config. The Pi does not know what resolution to set if the screen is off or not connected.

Answer (score 1):

I found there is a setting under Preferences, "Raspberry Pi Configuration", "Interfaces" for VNC.  Mine was set to Disable.  Once I set it to Enable and rebooted I was able to log in via VNC Viewer on my Mac.